# como criar uma udf utilizando duas colunas e if expressão

Tags: expressões-lambda, spark

Estou fazendo um trabalho usando PySpark and SQL

tenho essa função:

```
selection = F.udf(lambda x: cumulative_sum._1 if 100*random.random()<= x, FloatType())
cumulative_sum.withColumn('Selection2', selection(cumulative_sum.cumSum)
```

Minha tabela chama cumulative_sum e meu objetivo é checar se cada valor da coluna *cumSUm* é menor que um número gerado aleatoriamente, caso seja eu iria adicionar o respectivo valor da coluna _1 na nova coluna *Selection2*. Porém, quando executo esse código, tenho esse erro:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Como posso arrumar isso?

Comment: e ai, consegui?

Answer (score 0):

Vc precisa do `Else` no `if-else` de na mesma linha. Segue como deveria ser:

```py
selection = F.udf(lambda x: cumulative_sum._1 if 100*random.random()<= x else float(0.0), FloatType())
cumulative_sum.withColumn('Selection2', selection(cumulative_sum.cumSum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nao sei se entendi a pergunta direito, ja nao falo portugues a muito tempo.
E isso que queres fazer?

```py
df.withColumn('selection2', 
               when(F.lag('cumSum') < F.col('cumSum'), F.col('cumSum'))
               .otherwise(0.0) #ou .otherwise(None)
              )
```